# Laravel showing error which trying to access /api route

Tags: laravel-5.5

When trying to access `/api` route in browser or postman, I'm getting following error. The error trace:

```
"message": "Accept header could not be properly parsed because of a strict matching process.",
  "status_code": 400,
  "debug": {
    "line": 74,
    "file": "/usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/app/Wordpress/Http/Parser/Accept.php",
    "class": "Symfony\\Component\\HttpKernel\\Exception\\BadRequestHttpException",
    "trace": Array[11][
      "#0 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/app/Wordpress/Http/Validation/Accept.php(55): App\\Wordpress\\Http\\Parser\\Accept->parse(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), true)",
      "#1 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/app/Wordpress/Http/RequestValidator.php(102): App\\Wordpress\\Http\\Validation\\Accept->validate(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#2 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/app/Wordpress/Http/Middleware/Request.php(94): App\\Wordpress\\Http\\RequestValidator->validateRequest(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#3 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(149): App\\Wordpress\\Http\\Middleware\\Request->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request), Object(Closure))",
      "#4 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php(53): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#5 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(102): Illuminate\\Routing\\Pipeline->Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#6 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(151): Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline->then(Object(Closure))",
      "#7 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(116): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->sendRequestThroughRouter(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#8 /usr/local/var/www/htdocs/test-core/public/index.php(54): Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel->handle(Object(Illuminate\\Http\\Request))",
      "#9 /Users/sujitbaniya/.composer/vendor/laravel/valet/server.php(147): require('/usr/local/var/...')",
      "#10 {main}"
    ]
  }
```

The laravel version I'm using is `5.5`. Can anyone suggest me why this error occurred and what might be the solution?

**UPDATED**

```
//standardsTree = vnd
//subtype = insta
public function parse(Request $request, $strict = false)
    {
        $pattern = '/application\/'.$this->standardsTree.'\.('.$this->subtype.')\.([\w\d\.\-]+)\+([\w]+)/';

        if (! preg_match($pattern, $request->header('accept'), $matches)) {
            if ($strict) {
                throw new BadRequestHttpException('Accept header could not be properly parsed because of a strict matching process.');
            }

            $default = 'application/'.$this->standardsTree.'.'.$this->subtype.'.'.$this->version.'+'.$this->format;

            preg_match($pattern, $default, $matches);
        }

        return array_combine(['subtype', 'version', 'format'], array_slice($matches, 1));
    }

Passed Header: Accept application/json
```

Comment: share your file also `Wordpress/Http/Parser/Accept.php` ?

Comment: Also share your `Accept` header of the request as well as what they should match.

Comment: I've updated the question with parse() and Accept

Comment: Well if you send it `Accept application/json` and the server only can send back `application/vnd.insta` then failing is correct behaviour right?

Comment: adding `Accept application/vnd.insta` in header gave same error.

Comment: `/application\/'.$this->standardsTree.'\.('.$this->subtype.')\.([\w\d\.\-]+)\+([\w]+)/` is your regex. Make sure your accept headers match that. i.e. `application/vnd.insta.<version>+<format>`

Comment: That worked! Thanks. Though issue is thrown: `Class throttle does not exist` when defining: `Route::get('/home', function(Request $request) {
    return "Hello World";
});` for api.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166584/discussion-between-sujit-and-apokryfos).